# Difference between partitioning options in the mini installer

Tags: system-installation, 20.04

Ubuntu 20.04 mini installer iso, partitioning screen

[image]

What is the difference between

- Guided - **reuse** partition... (green arrow)

and

- Guided - **use entire** partition... (blue arrow)

??

Comment: Not sure and maybe mistaken, reuse would be without formatting and use be with formatting.  Imagine already has Ubuntu/Linux on it containing a / and /home partitions.